# Converting string into an object instance name - python

Tags: python, string, qt, object, tree

I'm probably going about this all wrong but...

I am trying to populate a QTreeView from SQL data - using QAbstractItemModel (and having a great deal of trouble understanding it tbh).  One of the tutorials I am following (the simplest) populates the Tree by simply calling new instances of the 'Node' and generating the model from the list.  The Node has a name and a parentnode (as below).  This is OK where you are generating the data within the program.  This I can just about follow :)

However, I want to bring the data in from the table and use a string to identify the correct parentnode - mainly because if I am iterating over the records I won't be able to name each one using a separate variable(?).  It will be for x in recs: node = Node("name", parentnode).

When I do this, I get the obvious error message that the string isnt the correct object and has no methods.  Is there a way of using a string derived from my table to identify the correct 'parent' object (either that, or could somebody point me in the direction of a very basic Qtreeview model tutorial designed for very enthusiastic, but not necessary gifted learners).

```
rootNode   = Node("Hips")
childNode0 = TransformNode("RightPirateLeg",        rootNode)
childNode1 = Node("RightPirateLeg_END",    childNode0)
childNode2 = CameraNode("LeftFemur",             rootNode)
childNode3 = Node("LeftTibia",             childNode2)
childNode4 = Node("LeftFoot",              childNode3)
childNode5 = LightNode("LeftFoot_END",          childNode4)
```

I realise that I am probably running before I can walk here and apologise in advance for my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the strings the names of global variables? If so, you can access the value refenced by the global variable with `globals()['name']`, (replacing `'name'` with the string name of the variable of course.)

Or, better yet, instead of littering variable names all over your global namespace
you could use a `dict`:

```
node={}
node['rootNode']=Node('Hips')
node['childNode0']=TransformNode('RightPirateLeg',node['rootNode'])
...
```

This makes it very easy to map between string names and values.

Comment: I hope you have chosen the second proposal. Having variables with indices is always an indication that you should use a container datatype like a list or a `dict`. @unutbu -1 for proposing the ugly `globals` stuff, that's not pythonic at all...

Comment: Just like to add that I have now incorporated using the dict approach with the SQLite data and it has worked (yippee!)  Very chuffed.  Thanks @unutbu